# The joy of resolving a philosophical doubt

Tags: epicurus, pain-and-pleasure, sources

In his [entry on Epicureanism](http://caae.phil.cmu.edu/Cavalier/80130/part1/sect2/texts/R_Epicurean.html) in the Routledge Encyclopedia of Philosophy, David Sedley wrote:

> "There are mental as well as bodily kinetic pleasures, for example, (perhaps) the 'joy' of resolving a philosophical doubt..."

Is this an example he thought up of or does this - or something similar - appear in Epicurus' or one of his students' writings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this *specific* example is probably something that the author thought up, but it is entirely consistent with the limited source material. In particular I can point to one such specific example from Epicurus's ["Letter to Menoeceus"](http://classics.mit.edu/Epicurus/menoec.html) in which the following is relevant.

> By pleasure we mean the absence of pain in the body and of trouble in the soul. It is not an unbroken succession of drinking-bouts and of merrymaking, not sexual love, not the enjoyment of the fish and other delicacies of a luxurious table, which produce a pleasant life; it is **sober reasoning, searching out the grounds of every choice and avoidance, and banishing those beliefs through which the greatest disturbances take possession of the soul**.

As an example, "the 'joy' of resolving a philosophical doubt" is very much consistent with the bolded portion above.